# How to get likes and shares count for a facebook post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor, fb-graph

I have a server side app with an access_token created using the facebook apps appKey and secret.

I use version 2.5 of facebook graph API and cannot use an older API version.

I want to get periodically stats on posts. The posts where created via the same facebook app but with the Facebook users logged in. So in my db I've got the userid_postid for each post.

If I query with the apps id and a posts id I get the expected results for some posts.

GET "{appKey}_{PostId}?fields=shares

If I query like this 'GET "{postingUserId}_{postId}?fields=shares' with the user id and the post id I get this error:

```
{
 "error": {
   "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
   "type": "GraphMethodException",
   "code": 100,
   "fbtrace_id": "AyT8LYQDlDd"
 }
```

}

A cron runs periodically a query to get number of likes and shares and it uses the appId and secret to get its access_token.

How do I query for informations on posts?

Comment: What data are you not getting when you query by PostID that would get by using PostID and UserId?

Comment: I get an error if I simple query with a postId. Tried it in Graph API Explorer v.2.5 with an app token.
{  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12,
    "fbtrace_id": "EP63na3YI/G"
  }
}

Comment: What was your query string? GET /v2.5/{post-id} is the supported endpoint for v2.5.

Comment: Where did you get the `postingUserId` from? Where is the post located (user/page/group timeline)?

Comment: Post-Id is the userid_postid otherwise I get an error in 2.5 or am I wrong? In my App Users are creating Posts, so the id is in my db. After that a cron runs periodically a query to get number of likes and shares. The cron Logs in with the Appid and secret to get its access_token.

Comment: The posts are in the timeline of a user

Comment: You'll need a user access token for the user who posted the post and the user_posts permission.